# Linear algebra find $k$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the linear system:

$$\begin{cases}
 x_1 + kx_2 − x_3 = 2\\ 
2x_1 − x_2 + kx_3 = 5 \\
x_1 +10x_2 −6x_3 =1
\end{cases}$$

for which values of $k$ has the system (2):
(a) No solutions
(b) A unique solution.
(c) Infinitely many solutions.

I've been trying echelon form where i switched $R_1$ with $R_3$ and then i switched $R_2$ with $R_3$

So I have $\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&10&-6&1\\1&k&-1&2\\2&-1&k&5\end{array}\right]$

but then I'm stuck and don't know how to get any further.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what value of K does the system have a unique solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4003621/what-value-of-k-does-the-system-have-a-unique-solution)

Comment: It need not have infinitely many solutions, if it's over a finite field, for instance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far could you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: @saulspatz thanks for the comment, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Matrix of coefficients is
$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & k & -1 \\
 2 & -1 & k \\
 1 & 10 & -6 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
$\det A=k^2+2 k-15$

If $\det A\ne 0\to k\ne 3;\;k\ne-5$ the system has one and only one solution.

If $k=3$ then $\det A=0$ and $\text{rank}(A)=\text{rank}(A|B)=2$ thus there are infinite solutions

$$A|B=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
 1 & 3 & -1 & 2 \\
 2 & -1 & 3 & 5 \\
 1 & 10 & -6 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
If $k=-5$
$$A|B=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & -5 & -1 & 2 \\
 2 & -1 & -5 & 5 \\
 1 & 10 & -6 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
$\text{rank}(A|B)=3$ while $\text{rank}(A)=2$. As ranks are different, the system has no solutions.

see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem#Formal_statement) for Rouchè-Capelli theorem